# how to move one field to the right among many other

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have list of text fields among which I want only one field to be moved to the right, i have used  but it is only moving the text box to the right without label.Can we do it without the help of CSS.

```
<tr align="right">
<td  oraLabel="mrId" class="oraLabel oraTableLabel"><label  for="mrId">
</label></td><td  class="oraNormal oraTableData"><input id="mrId"
class="oraInput" oraField="mrId">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you add more information please,it seems that you forgot some words

Comment: Yes sure. I have 4 fields, among which only one field should go to the extreme right of the page. above mentioned field is the one which i wanted it to be moved to right

Comment: If I tell you how to do it with js is like doing it with css,try to set on label align="right"

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at

- direction (It does not work if set to a single row. unless display is reset)

```css
tr[data-direction="right"] {
display:table;/* can only be set on table nowdays, not a single row ! */
direction: rtl; 
}

[data-direction="right"]>* {
 direction:ltr;
}
table, td {
 border:solid 1px;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-direction="right">
    <td oraLabel="mrId" class="oraLabel oraTableLabel">label<label for="mrId">
</label></td>
    <td class="oraNormal oraTableData"><input id="mrId" class="oraInput" oraField="mrId">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td oraLabel="mrId" class="oraLabel oraTableLabel"><label for="mrId2">label
</label></td>
    <td class="oraNormal oraTableData"><input id="mrId2" class="oraInput" oraField="mrId2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- or transform

```css
tr[data-direction="right"] {
  transform:scale(-1,1)
}

[data-direction="right"]>* {
  transform:scale(-1,1)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-direction="right">
    <td oraLabel="mrId" class="oraLabel oraTableLabel">label<label for="mrId">
</label></td>
    <td class="oraNormal oraTableData"><input id="mrId" class="oraInput" oraField="mrId">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td oraLabel="mrId" class="oraLabel oraTableLabel"><label for="mrId2">label
</label></td>
    <td class="oraNormal oraTableData"><input id="mrId2" class="oraInput" oraField="mrId2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Notes: 
When you do not want to use a class or any other known attributes, you can make your own valid attributes that DOM and CSS can access/filter. [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)